# How to use linq extension methods in T4

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I've been stackoverflowing and googling for a while trying to find an answer on how to use Linq extension methods in a T4 file.  I'm using VS 2012, .NET 4.5.

For example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myDict = GetSomeData();
```

Lets say I wanted to get the last item in the dictionary:

```
<#string last = colNames.Keys.Last();#>
```

It doesn't mind me using collections but it doesn't like the ".Last()".

> > Compiling transformation: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.KeyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.KeyCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've imported the necessary namespaces...

Edit -> For clarity... I have the following at the top of the T4 Template:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\SomeProject\bin\Debug\System.Data.Linq.Dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Linq" #>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your T4 Template includes a proper [Assembly Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586946.aspx) that references `System.Core.dll`, which is where LINQ is defined:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Core"#>
```

this is equivalent to *"Add Reference..."* in a regular C# project.

and then make sure you have a proper [Import Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586948.aspx) for the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq"#>
```

this is equivalent to a `using` directive in regular C# code.

Add these at the top of your `.tt` file.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  I do have the following: <#@ import namespace="System.Data.Linq" #> ... I even tried <#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\SomeProject\bin\Debug\System.Data.Linq.Dll" #>

Comment: @user3219570 `System.Data.Linq.dll` is **LINQ to SQL**. I think you need **LINQ to Objects**, which is defined in `System.Core.dll`.

Comment: AH!  Crud, good catch.  Unfortunately it doesn't like me to import the namespace System.Core (even though I have a reference)... I tried adding the System.Core reference to another project.  I then set it to copy local but it won't copy.  Any other tips?

Comment: @user3219570 the `System.Core` namespace does not exist. It's called `System.Linq` and it's defined in the `System.Core.dll` assembly. Are you sure you got that right?

Comment: You're correct... In my hasty typing, I made a typo.  I have "<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>"... But I get "The type or namespace 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'  ... I appreciate all the help

Comment: @user3219570 can you edit your question and post the current code after adding the directives mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I appreciate your time and fast responses.  I've been staring at this T4 file for too long.  To fix the issue, I added: <#@ assembly name="System.Core" #> and <#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>  I thought assembly references had to be made to physical dlls (thought I read that on another blog).  Either way, you saved me a ton of time.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user3219570 yes, assembly references have to be made to physical dlls, however, just by using the assembly name (with no path) you're telling .Net to search for that assembly in the GAC, and it finds it there.